# SCSt - java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class com.example.Sensor

Tags: avro, spring-cloud-stream

Getting a ClassCastException in a simple Spring Cloud Stream application sending and receiving avro message. If I use a Supplier functional interface, the message seems to be converted using a JSON converter and getting an exception about something not being an array.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.schema.registry.client.EnableSchemaRegistryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.schema.registry.client.SchemaRegistryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.util.MimeType;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSchemaRegistryClient
public class TestAvroSpringBootApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @Autowired
    SchemaRegistryClient client;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestAvroSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Random random = new Random();
        Sensor sensor = Sensor.newBuilder()
            .setId("sensor")
            .setAcceleration(random.nextFloat())
            .setTemperature(random.nextFloat())
            .setVelocity(random.nextFloat())
            .build();
        send(sensor);
    }

    void send(Sensor sensor) {
        streamBridge.send("sensor", sensor, MimeType.valueOf("application/+avro"));
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Sensor> consume() {
        return (sensor) -> { 
            System.out.println("Received Type:" + sensor.getClass().getCanonicalName());
            System.out.println("Received:" + sensor);
            };
    }

}
```

Partial output

```
2020-11-02 14:22:34.880 ERROR 10816 --- [request-queue-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@1105b3c7]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class com.example.Sensor (java.lang.Object is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.Sensor is in unnamed module of loader 'app'), failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[19], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=test-exchange, amqp_deliveryTag=1, deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=test-exchange.test-request-queue, amqp_redelivered=false, accept=application/+avro, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=test-exchange, amqp_timestamp=Mon Nov 02 14:22:31 EST 2020, amqp_messageId=8d30116d-118c-351e-45cf-722776880c20, id=25ff4f92-1f13-e2c1-5ce6-56fbe4dc0838, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-sPLzvmzTENJYL_0H4IpCiQ, sourceData=(Body:'[B@6f167bca(byte[19])' MessageProperties [headers={accept=application/+avro}, timestamp=Mon Nov 02 14:22:31 EST 2020, messageId=8d30116d-118c-351e-45cf-722776880c20, contentType=application/vnd.sensor.v1+avro, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=test-exchange, receivedRoutingKey=test-exchange, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-sPLzvmzTENJYL_0H4IpCiQ, consumerQueue=test-exchange.test-request-queue]), contentType=application/vnd.sensor.v1+avro, timestamp=1604344951852}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:104)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:69)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1300(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.lambda$onMessage$0(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:294)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:290)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1591)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1510)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1489)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1433)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:975)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:921)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1296)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1202)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class com.example.Sensor (java.lang.Object is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.Sensor is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.invokeFunction(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:530)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:599)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:453)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:441)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.apply(PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.java:71)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionWrapper.apply(FunctionConfiguration.java:609)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper$HandlerMethod.invoke(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:582)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:477)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:355)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:108)
    ... 30 more
```

application.yml. My STS 4.2.0.RELEASE warns me of unknown property if I leave the schema-registry configuration under spring.cloud.stream, so I moved them up

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.cloud: debug
    com.example: debug
spring:
  cloud:
    schema-registry-client:
      endpoint: http://localhost:8990/registry/
      cached: true
    schema:
      avro:
        prefix: vnd
        schema-locations: classpath:avro/sensor.avsc
    stream:
#      schema-registry-client:
#        endpoint: http://localhost:8990/registry/
#      schema:
#        avro:
#          schema-locations: classpath:avro/sensor.avsc
      function:
        bindings:
          consume-in-0: consume1
      bindings:
        sensor:
          destination: test-exchange
          group: test-request-queue
          content-type: application/*+avro
          producer:
            requiredGroups: test-request-queue
            bindingRoutingKey: test-request-key
        consume1:
          destination: test-exchange
          group: test-request-queue
          content-type: application/*+avro
          consumer:
            requiredGroups: test-request-queue
      binders:
        local_rabbit:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: localhost
                port: 5672
                username: guest
                password: guest
                virtual-host: /
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <groupId>test-avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-avro</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>schemas</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schema</goal>
                        <goal>protocol</goal>
                        <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>                        
                        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: `>Partial output` - you need to show the complete stack trace; truncating it like that renders it completely useless.

Comment: Full stack trace added. Please let me know if you need other debug outputs as well

Comment: Show your `application.yml` and state what versions of spring-cloud-stream/function you are using.

Comment: Added pom.xml and application.yml

Comment: @GaryRussell, is there an issue with the version I am using or a configuration error?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the Avro stuff; I was just prompting you to add sufficient information for someone to help. That said, it looks like the avro conversion is creating an `Object` instead of your `Sensor`.

Comment: I see that `AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter` is used internally to convert the avro message to java object and when I examine the `convertFromInternal` method, the `targetClass` passed in is a `java.lang.Object` class. It appears that `SmartMessageMethodArgumentResolver` is the class that is responsible for determining the targetClass. Not sure if there is a problem here as to how the targetClass is determined or if the problem is with the StreamBridge which sends the message as a `GenericMessage` instead of some other type of message that could be inferred to be of the avro type.

Comment: If I implement a custom `AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter` and override convertFromInternal and call the super implementation with correct `targetClass` (Sensor.class), it works. So, the problem seems to be in `SmartMessageMethodArgumentResolver` figuring out the correct targetClass

Comment: It should be able to determine the required type `Sensor` from the `consume()` return type. I don't think it's a problem with `StreamBridge`, it's on the consumer side. I am not familiar with that part of the code base; perhaps type erasure is the problem. I suggest you open an issue against [spring-cloud-stream](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues). But it's good that you have a work-around.

Comment: I tried the code above and could not reproduce this issue with Kafka binder. Here is a sample with the Kafka binder: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/schema-registry-samples/spring-schema-registry-kafka-standalone

Comment: Also, added some comments here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/1022#issuecomment-776372566